# My Expert Advisor doesn't work. The problem is on if blocks i think

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

There is part of my code. Why can't I buy or sell? I use iMAOnArray and when I use if blocks for trade I have to use array format like "Fark[i]". Could it be that ?

```
 for(i=0; i<=limit; i++)
 {FarkM[i]=(PlusSdiBuffer[i]-MinusSdiBuffer[i]);} 

 for(i=0; i<=limit; i++)
 {FarkM[i]=(PlusSdiBuffer[i]-MinusSdiBuffer[i]);
 Fark[i]=iMAOnArray(FarkM,Bars,ADXPeriod,0,MODE_EMA,i);} 

 for(i=0; i<=limit; i++)
 {Ortalama[i]=iMAOnArray(Fark,Bars,ADXPeriod,0,MODE_EMA,i);} 

 for(i=0; i<=limit; i++)
 {FarkOnce[i]=iMAOnArray(FarkM,Bars,ADXPeriod,0,MODE_EMA,i-1);} 

 for(i=0; i<=limit; i++)
 {OrtalamaOnce[i]=iMAOnArray(Fark,Bars,ADXPeriod,0,MODE_EMA,i-1);} 


   ATR=iATR(_Symbol,_Period,14,0);

   karalbuy=Ask+(ATR*2.5);

   stopbuy=Ask-ATR;

   karalsell=Bid-(ATR*2.5); 

  stopsell=Bid+ATR;


  if((Fark[i]>Ortalama[i])&&(OrtalamaOnce[i]>FarkOnce[i]))
  {int buyticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,0.01,Ask,3,stopbuy,karalbuy,NULL,0,0,clrRed);}

  if(Fark[i]<Ortalama[i]&&FarkOnce[i]>OrtalamaOnce[i])
  {int sellticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,0.01,Bid,3,stopsell,karalsell,NULL,0,0,clrBlue);}
```

Comment: try to print down the values of the buffers you received with `iMAOnArray()` function, problem might be there. Also, it might be easier to move all the logic of buffers into an indicator and use `iCustom()` to get those values (Fark, Ortalama, FarkOnce etc).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Sir. I have a indicator that works with these 'iMaOnArray's and it work perfect. Can i send order with that indicator by using iCustom on a Expert Advisor ?

Comment: yes, use iCustom to be indicator values and send it from the EA.